# He's out the door

Tags: sentence-meaning

**He's out the door**.

---

Which tense is correct?

1- He **is going out** the door.

2- He **has gone out** the door.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: 'Out the door' looks wrong to me, though I see that Merriam-Webster accepts it. See https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/walk-out-of-the-door-or-out-the-door-look-out-of-the-window-or-out-the-window.3207287/

Answer (score 1):

The image shows a person in the process of going out of the door.  In a moment, assuming he doesn't stop or turn around, he will be out the door.

So at the current instant in the image, he "is going" out the door.  Once he has passed through the door, you could say that he "has gone out the door".

"is going" is present tense.  It's happening now.

"has gone" is past tense.  It happened in the past.